# Batch Color Selection Error

Tags: windows, batch-file

Im having trouble with a batch program, where Im trying to learn to have a user input the color of choice. The problem is, when I input the value I want and press enter the program closes. I have Windows 10 64x

```
@echo off

:setcolor
set /p %color%= "What color text do you want? [0-White  1-Blue  2-Green  3-Red  4-Yellow]"
if %color% EQU 0 goto :1 
if %color% EQU 1 goto :2
if %color% EQU 2 goto :3
if %color% EQU 3 goto :4
if %color% EQU 4 goto :5
goto :setcolor

:1
color 07
goto :main 
:2
color 01
goto :main
:3
color 02
goto :main
:4
color 0c
goto :main
:5
color 06
goto :main

:main
echo test
pause
```

Comment: `set /p color="What Color"` or better `set /p "color=What Color"` Use `%` only, if you want to *expand*  a variable.

Comment: If my answer helps, please tick the checkmark next to my answer to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

As @Stephan mentioned, `set /p %color%=` should be changed to `set /p color=`.

When setting variables, we don't put `%`s around the variable(expand it), but we enter the name of the variable.

So, here's your code:

```
@echo off

:setcolor
set /p color="What color text do you want? [0-White  1-Blue  2-Green  3-Red  4-Yellow]"
if "%color%" EQU "0" goto :1 
if "%color%" EQU "1" goto :2
if "%color%" EQU "2" goto :3
if "%color%" EQU "3" goto :4
if "%color%" EQU "4" goto :5
goto :setcolor

    .....
```

---

By the way, I added quotes(`"`) to the `%color%` and numbers to prevent the batch file stops when encountering empty inputs or inputs with space